# Slow REST API calls on self-hosted WordPress

Tags: api, plugin-jetpack, plugin-json-api, rest-api

I'm using WordPress REST API to access some posts from an app we're creating, but the API calls are really slow!

If I'm using the domain in the call like this:

`https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/www.example.com/posts/?`

it takes ~3000ms to load.

If I'm using the site-id, it "only" takes 2000 ms. Is there anything I can do to speed things up? Is there any way to access the API directly through my own domain like `http://example.com/rest/v1.1/posts/`?

Comment: Are you sending these requests to self-hosted site or to some blog on wordpress.com?

Comment: A very old question, not sure OP is looking for the answer any longer ;)